# How to change text color of a String mentioned between a Text

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView. Setting text on Textview and including a String between text like below code.

How to change color and text style of String in Android.

```
tv.setText("some text"+String+"some text")
```

Comment: You can use SpannableString. Check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTLmz-JKxsI and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxV6EAgrdYs

Comment: You should really make your question more clear, and add tags for any frameworks or languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Foreground Color Span class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan)

```
String yourString = "color me red";
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(yourString);
ForegroundColorSpan red = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
spannableString.setSpan(red, 9, 11, Spanned,SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(spannableString);
```

The code above would change the color of "red" in your string to red as defined in ForegroundColorSpan. You would have to define where your span starts and ends, as in my case item 9 to 11 on the string array.

Comment: But I don't know where string starts and where it's ending.

Comment: This trick worked for me. Thanks

````
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Text "+String+" Text");
ForegroundColorSpan red = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
spannableString.setSpan(red,4, 4+String.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(spannableString)
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpannableString`

```
Spannable span = new SpannableString("some text" + String + "some text");
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 8, String.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move your entire text to strings.xml and use CDATA

```
  <string name="tvText">        
    <![CDATA[
        some text <font face="sans-serif-thin" color=#000000> text to color </font> some text
    ]]>    
</string>
```

In your code you would use Html Parser to load

```
 tv.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(getString(R.string.tvText), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Answer (score 0):

This trick worked for me. Thanks, everyone for the suggestions.

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Text "+String+" Text");
ForegroundColorSpan red = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
spannableString.setSpan(red,4, 4+String.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(spannableString)
```